# Android Pay now requires me to enter my pin twice

Tags: google-pay

Usually when using Android Pay I would unlock my phone with a pin and then be able to pay. Since the switch to Google Pay I have to unlock my phone with a pin, try to pay, get a prompt asking me to enter my pin, enter my pin, push the green button on the terminal, and then i'm able to pay. Does anyone know of a fix for this as it would be quicker to just use my card.

Comment: According to the chat I just had with Google support, this is an intentional change though in my case, I initially unlock with the fingerprint reader